# AFNetworking + SOAP web service

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, soap, afnetworking

I have an application consuming a SOAP Web service using ASIHttpRequest, now i want ( or have ) to use other network framework and i chose AFNetworking, but can't see how can i do for SOAP consuming, her's how i do with ASIHttpRequest :

```
NSString *operation=[NSString stringWithString:@"search_service"];
NSString *xmlNamespace=[NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.xxx.com/wsdl"];
NSString *address=[NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.xxx.com/service"];
NSString *parameters=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<param1>%@</param1><param2>%@</param2>",
                      @"val1",
                      @"val2",
                      ];

NSString *operatorTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ xmlns=\"%@\">%@</%@>\n", operation, xmlNamespace, parameters, operation];

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<s:Envelope xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n"
                         "  <s:Header>\n"
                         "    <To xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">%@</To>\n"
                         "    <a:Action>http://tempuri.org/IService1/%@</a:Action>\n"
                         "  </s:Header>\n"
                         "  <s:Body>\n"
                         "    %@"
                         "  </s:Body>\n"
                         "</s:Envelope>\n", address, operation, operatorTag
                         ];

asiRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:address]];
[asiRequest setDelegate:self];
[asiRequest addRequestHeader:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" value:@"Content-Type"];
[asiRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[asiRequest setPostBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[asiRequest startAsynchronous];
```

**Edit** : this is what i try with AFNetworking :

```
NSString *operationWSDL= @"search_service";
NSString *xmlNamespace= @"http://www.xxx.com/wsdl";
NSString *address= @"http://www.xxx.com/service";
NSString *parameters=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<param1>%@</param1><param2>%@</param2>",@"val1",@"val2",];


NSString *operatorTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ xmlns=\"%@\">%@</%@>\n", operationWSDL, xmlNamespace, parameters, operationWSDL];

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<s:Envelope xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n"
                         "  <s:Header>\n"
                         "    <To xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">%@</To>\n"
                         "    <a:Action>http://tempuri.org/IService1/%@</a:Action>\n"
                         "  </s:Header>\n"
                         "  <s:Body>\n"
                         "    %@"
                         "  </s:Body>\n"
                         "</s:Envelope>\n", address, operationWSDL, operatorTag
                         ];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxx.com/service"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",@"Content-Type", nil] body:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and did not work? We are here help, but where not here to write code for you.

Comment: yes maybe my question make you think this. i edit my question with what i try to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WSDL2Objc? http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/. 
I used it in my project lately. It successfully generates classes(from consumed WSDL) to work with SOAP service. I think it will be better solution.

Comment: thank you, i try it before ( in other project-web service ) and it work just fine but with this one the returned value is empty and i cant change any thing in server so i abort this solution .

Comment: Warning.  I tried WSDL2Objc with very little success.  ARC support is stuck in a non-release branch.  Several WSDL's that I use would fail when generating the code.  Last release was almost 3 yrs ago.

Comment: Try SudzC for Objective-C ARC and non-ARC WSDL auto code generation. I found it works very well indeed. http://sudzc.com/